# Unable to add PostGIS table to Geoserver

Tags: postgis, geoserver, shapefile

I am able to add individual tables to Geoserver using,

```
curl -u admin:geoserver -v -XPOST -H 'Content-type: text/xml' -d '<featureType><name>quadrella_indica</name></featureType>' http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/opengeo/datastores/species/featuretypes
```

But I need to loop through the entire list of shp file and so,

```
for f in *.shp
   do 
   a=${f,,};
   curl -u admin:geoserver -v -XPOST -H 'Content-type: text/xml' -d    '<featureType><name>${a%.*}</name></featureType>' http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/opengeo/datastores/species/featuretypes 
done
```

Only returns a 400 Bad request error,

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying ::1... connected
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> POST /geoserver/rest/workspaces/opengeo/datastores/species/featuretypes HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46Z2Vvc2VydmVy
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> Content-type: text/xml
> Content-Length: 47
> 
* upload completely sent off: 47out of 47 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Sun, 25 Nov 2012 18:19:31 GMT
< Connection: close
< 
* Closing connection #0
Trying to create new feature type inside the store, but no attributes were specified
```

The above error is repeated for all the shp files that are being added to geoserver. Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not solve why this was not working and so ended up creating a perl command that works just fine.

http://dpaste.com/839047/